# python matplotlib colormap gets inherited by subsequent plots as well

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have two plots using matlpotlib in python. In the first one, I have a colormap `plt.summer()`. Unfortunately my second plot also inherits this colormap. How can I stop the first one from propagating its specs to other plots? How can I turn it off once I pass to another plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
matplotlib.cm.set_cmap(cm.jet)
```

Or

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
cmap = plt.get_cmap('BlueRed2')
plt.scatter(x, y, c=t, cmap=cmap)
...
```